# mod_rewrite - PHP: $_GET not complete

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have the following mod_rewrite:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^register index.php?page=register
```

The url looks like this: `http://domain.com/register?param=foo&paramtwo=bar`
If I now print $_GET in PHP I get this: `Array ( [page] => register )` but the other params aren't set. Must I change someting at the mod_rewrite to get them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the *QSA* flag to have the original query appended to the new one:

```
RewriteRule ^register index.php?page=register [QSA]
```